# 1996 corolla periodically won’t start

Tags: no-crank-no-start

I have a 96 corolla that doesn’t start sometimes. When I go to turn it on, the radio and light turn on, as well as the fan near the radiator, but the car won’t budge. Other than the fan near the radiator, I don’t hear Anything else. The battery is relatively new, so I doubt it is that.

Comment: What then happens in order to make it start again? Do you have to wait a certain amount of time?

Comment: Have you tried wiggling the key when in start position?  Also, shift out of park and into neutral and try again.

Comment: I figured out what happened. I recently did an engine swap, and forgot to ground the starter. Professional, right? Thanks for the responses though